# Using a panel from another panel in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm new using wxpython.

I created some code to generate a splitter window, in the left panel I created a listbox and in the right panel I created a button.

What I would like to do is that when I press my button in the right panel, my list in the left panel display the string "Hello World".

I've tried the following:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class LeftPanel(wx.Panel):
""""""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
    """Constructor"""
       wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

           self.lizt = wx.ListBox(self, -1, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = (300,     120), choices = "", style = wx.LB_SINGLE|wx.LB_HSCROLL|wx.LB_SORT, name = "aDB")

           sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
           sizer.Add(self.lizt, 0, wx.EXPAND)
           self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class RightPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

   #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
    """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
            txt = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "txt") 
            txt.SetLabel("ALL")
            txt.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.write, txt)

    def write(self, event): 
        LeftPanel.lizt.Clear()
        LeftPanel.lizt.Append("HELLO WORLD")
        return

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Splitter Tutorial")

        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        leftP = LeftPanel(splitter)
        rightP = RightPanel(splitter)

        # split the window
        splitter.SplitVertically(leftP, rightP)
        splitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

But I get this Error: AttributeError: type object 'LeftPanel' has no attribute 'lizt'

What am I doing wrong :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the 'LeftPanel' class and not the instance of that class. 'lizt' doesn't exist until you create an instance of the 'LeftPanel' class. To reference the left panel from the right panel you must first create a persistent reference to the left panel in the main frame.

instead of

```
leftP = LeftPanel(splitter)
```

do

```
self.leftP = LeftPanel(splitter)
```

then from the right panel's 'write' method you have to find the reference to the left panel.

```
parent = self.GetParent()
left_panel = parent.leftP
left_panel_list = left_panel.lizt
```

There's obviously easier ways to save references, you could explicitly pass the left panel's list to the right panel's **init** method. Or more preferably move everything to the **init** method of the frame and save all references to the frame's instance. As a general tip, remember the local variables in your **init** methods go away when the **init** method is done unless you explicitly save them to the class. If you're planning on referencing the lists, panels, etc later, save the references to the class (**self.leftP** instead of just **leftP**)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response :)
I've tried and it worked perfectly.